# get name of tuples that match an entire column in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to select every `name` from `table1` where there's tuples that match every `type` from `table2` without grouping or aggregate functions.

```
 table1        table2
name|type     type|info
 a  | 1         1 | .
 a  | 2         2 | ..
 a  | 3         3 | ...
 b  | 1
 b  | 2  
 b  | 3         
 c  | 2
```

From here, it should output

```
name|
 a  |
 b  |
```

edit:
ended up doing something like

```
SELECT distinct outside.name 
FROM table1 outside
WHERE '' NOT IN
[ (SELECT *  
   FROM table1 t 
   WHERE t.name=outside.name) 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
  table2 ]
```

Second select makes a table with empty values for names that don't have a type in table2. So if '' isn't in the second select that means it has a tuple for every type in table2. I think

Comment: As you work on this, make sure to share what you've tried! It always helps to know the person posting the question is working on the problem too.

Comment: Would a full join or something work? something like: 
SELECT t1.name FROM table1 t1 WHERE null not in (select * from table1 t2 WHERE t2.name=t1.name) JOIN table2. Not even sure if you can even do this, I'm still new to sql

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t1.name
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.type = t1.type)
group by t1.name
having count(distinct t1.type) = (select count(distinct t2.type) from table2);
```

This filters `t1` down to the matches in `t2`.  It then counts the number that match.

This uses `count(distinct)`, which allows duplicates in the respective tables.  If there are no duplicates, then just use `count()`.

Comment: I can't use group by or count